# Search by pattern, and copy within the same folder but with a different name

Tags: find, cp, exec

This is the folder structure:

/home/user/Pictures/Vacation/Italy/Rome/photo.**front**.001.jpg

Within the folder Rome I have many other photos, but I'm only interested in the ones that have "**front**" in the filename. Of these I should make a copy and call it "**fanart.jpg**" (still in the Rome folder).

I'd like to do this for all the folders stored in Italy parent folder.

I've been trying to use `find` to search for this pictures, but then I'm not able to make a copy with a different name.

Do you have an idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `-execdir` to make a copy relative to the directory of the found file(s) e.g.

```
find Italy -name '*.front.*' -execdir cp -- {} 'fanart.jpg' \;
```

Example: given

```
$ tree Italy/
Italy/
├── Florence
│   ├── photo.back.001.jpg
│   ├── photo.back.002.jpg
│   ├── photo.back.003.jpg
│   ├── photo.front.001.jpg
│   ├── photo.front.002.jpg
│   └── photo.front.003.jpg
├── Naples
│   ├── photo.back.001.jpg
│   ├── photo.back.002.jpg
│   ├── photo.back.003.jpg
│   ├── photo.front.001.jpg
│   ├── photo.front.002.jpg
│   └── photo.front.003.jpg
└── Rome
    ├── photo.back.001.jpg
    ├── photo.back.002.jpg
    ├── photo.back.003.jpg
    ├── photo.front.001.jpg
    ├── photo.front.002.jpg
    └── photo.front.003.jpg

3 directories, 18 files
```

Then

```
$ find Italy -name '*.front.*' -execdir cp -v -- {} 'fanart.jpg' \;
‘./photo.front.001.jpg’ -> ‘fanart.jpg’
‘./photo.front.003.jpg’ -> ‘fanart.jpg’
‘./photo.front.002.jpg’ -> ‘fanart.jpg’
‘./photo.front.001.jpg’ -> ‘fanart.jpg’
‘./photo.front.003.jpg’ -> ‘fanart.jpg’
‘./photo.front.002.jpg’ -> ‘fanart.jpg’
‘./photo.front.001.jpg’ -> ‘fanart.jpg’
‘./photo.front.003.jpg’ -> ‘fanart.jpg’
‘./photo.front.002.jpg’ -> ‘fanart.jpg’
```

(note that if there are multiple files matching the `*.front.*` pattern, the copy gets successively overwritten - if that's not what you want, add `-n` or `--no-clobber`), resulting in

```
$ tree Italy/
Italy/
├── Florence
│   ├── fanart.jpg
│   ├── photo.back.001.jpg
│   ├── photo.back.002.jpg
│   ├── photo.back.003.jpg
│   ├── photo.front.001.jpg
│   ├── photo.front.002.jpg
│   └── photo.front.003.jpg
├── Naples
│   ├── fanart.jpg
│   ├── photo.back.001.jpg
│   ├── photo.back.002.jpg
│   ├── photo.back.003.jpg
│   ├── photo.front.001.jpg
│   ├── photo.front.002.jpg
│   └── photo.front.003.jpg
└── Rome
    ├── fanart.jpg
    ├── photo.back.001.jpg
    ├── photo.back.002.jpg
    ├── photo.back.003.jpg
    ├── photo.front.001.jpg
    ├── photo.front.002.jpg
    └── photo.front.003.jpg
```

---

If your system's version of `find` doesn't support `-execdir` an alternate way would be to remove the filename portion of the full pathname - for example using POSIX parameter expansion of the form `"${var%/*}"` - and replace it with the newname in a little inline shell command `sh -c`

```
find Italy -name '*.front.*' -exec sh -c 'cp -v -- "$1" "${1%/*}/fanart.jpg"' sh {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a requirement to use `find`? For things like that, I find loops to be more appropriate:

```
$ cd /home/user/Pictures/Vacation/Italy
$ for directory in *; do \
    cd "$directory" && \
    for file in *front*; do \
        cp --force "$file" fanart.jpg; \
    done; \
    cd /home/user/Pictures/Vacation/Italy; \
  done
```

Essentially, this just goes through subdirectories of "Italy" and for each of them, copies files with "Front" in their name to a file named "fanart.jpg" (overwriting things, because the destination filename is constant.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I don't have a requirement to use find, but when executing the script you made it gives me: line 8: syntax error: unexpected end of file. I'm not very familiar with code.

Comment: Ah, sorry—forgot a semicolon after "fanart.jpg". Should work now.